# Why size of stack not auto-fits on device screen? - Livecode

Tags: livecode

everyone

I create stack size 768*1024.This's size for iPad or iPad Retina.My images have size 768*1024.

I tested on emulator.My images not fits.Picture below.

[image]

This code:

```
on preOpenstack
   if the environment is "mobile" then
      set the acceleratedRendering of this stack to true
   end if
   set the fullScreenMode of this stack to "exactFit"
   put the short name of the first grp into grpname
   set the layerMode of group grpname  to "scrolling" 
end preOpenstack
```

And I setting size&position follow this.

[image]

How do I do?

Thank you.

Excuse me.I'm not good english.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work is because you have an error in your scrip. To be notified of errors like this at runtime, add the following script to your stack script:

```
on errorDialog pError
   answer pError
end errorDialog
```

Something like this will appear on screen:

```
87,7,22
77,8,22
449,8,4,scrolling
...
...
```

The key number os the "7". The second item on line 1 tells your the line number of your script that is throwing the runtime error.

In the case of your script it is the fact you are getting the short name of your group which is returning "group ID xx" because you've not named the group. So in the following line:

```
set the layerMode of group grpname  to "scrolling"
```

you are actually executing:

```
set the layerMode of group group id xx to "scrolling"
```

Because the are getting the short name of the first group.. you can fix the issue by setting the layerMode property directly on the group like this:

```
set the layerMode of group 1 to "scrolling"
```

Comment: I input "errorDialog" in my code.It's not error message.

Comment: Hi, the script you posted has the error I explained below. Perhaps you updated your code since. You'd need to expand on your question to help us answer it.